# Persisting and applying Linq Query to collection

Tags: c#, .net, linq, appdomain

I have a scenario where I would want a plugin to construct a LINQ (to objects) query, send it across an appdomain and then apply and run it against a collection of my choosing

Is it possible, how?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a the [Dynamic Linq Library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) may be it can help you

Answer (score 0):

Expression trees are not serialisable because they contain references to code.  You might want to use an alternative format for describing your query across your AppDomain boundary, such as xml, etc.